# This code can't run, please. Tell me why?

Tags: ios

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class sipinViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDragDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        return cell
    }

    let  addipArray = [" 1 ","2"  ,"3  "]

    //章节里有几个cell。箭头号表示回传，一定要用return回传一个值。
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return addipArray.count
    }

    //cell里显示的内容。
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = addipArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

running   can't work.   I don't know  why?  thanks  for your time.

Comment: What does it mean `it cannot work`?

Comment: ？what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inherit protocol `UITableViewDelegate` with `UITableViewDataSource`.
Without `UITableViewDelegate` it's delegate method will not call.

Please check my below code.

`class sipinViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
}`

Comment: Hello, now I add a proxy, but I don't know this return value has been wrong. Excuse me, which is the return value array here? Thank you.